# IdentityServer4 Implicit Grant, Client and User account

Tags: identityserver4

I'm kinda new on using identityserver4, I've read articles for the past few days and I've encountered a problem or maybe simply my knowledge is not enough; anyway my questions are:

- Since I will be building an angularjs application as per my understanding I should stick with the Implicit Grant type, now my concern is the app that i'm building authenticate its user first (username - password), but that user will belong to a Client is this okay?
- With this upon looking into lots of sample app on one of the example that I'm currently using or referencing on its Client Project within the Startup.cs, Configure method it has:

  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
  {
      ClientId = "openIdConnectClient",
      Authority = "https://localhost:44350",
      SignInScheme = "cookie"
  });

Base on the code this new OpenIdConnectOptions is expecting a ClientId
but my problem is the only time ClientId will be available is when the user logins, I did try removing that but obviously the authorization didn't happen so to be short how do I implement this without hardcoding this ClientId and it will be base on the user client account info.

- Last is my understanding might be at fault here because my plan is to use the Client class as the specific client or to say those client that is subscribing to the the web app (it will have its own client registration and subscription page) and base on that client account it will or can have multiple users accounts, do the Client class or model of the IdentityServer serve this purpose?

I hope I make sense.

TIA.